# Problem with operator &&

Tags: c#, operators

Considering the following code

```
    public bool GetFalse()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public bool GetTrue()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

How can I force this expression `GetFalse() && GetTrue()` to execute second Method?

Comment: You are using the short-circuited `and` operator so the expression fails as soon as it is not possible to evaluate to `true`.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd recommend not relying on both to be executed.  It sounds like the actual GetFalse() or GetTrue() has some side effects if both are required to be executed.

Comment: @jglouie: Agreed.  If they both need to be executed then you should just call them separately and check the result later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't because the logical AND operator short circuits.  In the general case it is a good idea to avoid side effects from expressions like that, although there are perfectly valid uses (i.e., `if( someObj != null && someObj.Value == whatever )`.  You could use the bitwise and operator (`&`) which does not short circuit, but again, I wouldn't do that.

You should split those two method calls into variables first and then perform the check if you need them both to execute.

```
bool first = SomeMethodCall();
bool second = SomeMethodThatMustExecute();

if( first && second )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: However & won't short circuit.

Comment: @blowdart: Yeah, I was editing.  It's always a race around here :).  Probably shouldn't do that though.

Comment: If you split the calls (instead of using `&`) then someone else reading that code (or you, in a couple of months) will see that both methods are called always. You don't have to remember the difference between `&` and `&&`.

Answer (score 6):

Try with:

```
GetFalse() & GetTrue()
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest actually doing this (even though it answers the question).  Just call them separately.

Answer (score 4):

Use the non-short circuiting version (also known as the bit-wise AND when not working with Boolean values):

```
GetFalse() & GetTrue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimization issue.  Since the first method called in the expression is false, the entire expression cannot be true, so the second method in the expression is not called.  If it is necessary to call this for a side effect (bad practice to rely on a side effect, but YMMV), something like this should be used:

```
x = GetFalse(); 
y = GetTrue(); 
if (x && y) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your actual functions perform some specific tasks and return a value indicating (for example) success or failure I would prefer to see this written as

```
bool fooResult = DoFoo();
bool barResult = DoFar();
```

And then you can use `fooResult && barResult` in your code.